# Flink SQL : Cast Bigint into Timesamp

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

the question is pretty simple but I couldn't find any answer on the internet.

I have a Flink SQL query that look like this :

```
SELECT 
  HOP_START(timestampMs, INTERVAL '5' SECOND, INTERVAL '10' SECOND) as wStart, SUM(`value`) - MINVALUE(`value`), ID
FROM MySource 
GROUP BY HOP(timestampMs, INTERVAL '5' SECOND, INTERVAL '10' SECOND), ID
```

The problem is that my field timestampMs is seen as a `BIGINT` instead of a `TIMESTAMP`, and I have an error on the `HOP` functions. How can I cast it into `TIMESTAMP` type ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no built in support to convert from Epoch Millis to `java.sql.Timestamp`. You can use a UDF for that:

```
class UnixEpochToTimestamp extends ScalarFunction {
  def eval(epochMillis: Long): Timestamp = {
    new Timestamp(epochMillis)
  }
}
```

Comment: When I do so, I get the following error : `Cast function cannot convert value of type BIGINT to type TIMESTAMP(3)`

Comment: Is your timestamp in epoch millis? Also, see my updated answer

Comment: Yes my timesamp is in epoch millis. I am surprised that I have to create and UDF for something that simple.

Comment: I agree. You'll find quite a few surprises when working with the SQL API :)

Comment: People always like solving hard problems instead of focusing on the simple stuff.

Comment: @twalthr Sometimes the simple stuff is what makes a good user experience ;)